# Что я хочу сделать - так это

Tags: тире

Можете сказать, какой вар. корректный таки?

1. Что я хочу сделать - так это найти мой спиннинг.
2. Что я хочу сделать так это найти мой спиннинг.

Comment: сложноподчиненное предложение, Я =/= это. Это =что, то есть Это - дополнение, тире тут не нужно, нужна запятая или двоеточие. Тире было бы если бы Это конкурировало бы с Я за роль главного подлежащего, а Это относится к тому что я хочу сделать: я хочу сделать что/я хочу найти мой спиннинг.